# Do web servers normally limit how much hardware resources you use?

Tags: web, webserver

Hello there I am currently with a host known as Site5 and they have a limit on how many "resource points" I can use. On this site, resource points are a measurement on how much hardware resources I have used.

The way they describe it in the links [here](http://kb.site5.com/policies-and-information/resource-points/resource-point-overview/) state that 1 minute of CPU time = 1 resource point, and I have a daily limit of 250 points.

Since I've never used other web hosts, do other web hosts limit these sort of things?

Comment: That sounds very strange, are you sure you're describing it correctly?  I can't imagine putting such a strict limitation on a database, you could exceed that easily.  Can you provide a link detailing the specifics of what you're talking about?

Comment: Hi there, sure I can give you a link: http://kb.site5.com/policies-and-information/resource-points/resource-point-overview/

Comment: I found it really strange as well as all my friends have said that they have never heard of that either, and it is really easy for me (since I'm developing an app for many users) to exceed that at any time.

Comment: Ok, that link explains things pretty well.  Your description of how it works is incorrect :)  It's actually based on CPU time, 1 minute of CPU time = 1 resource point.  I've never heard of it being done that way, but that does sound like a decent way to determine usage

Comment: Cheers for the help :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help shed some light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, most (if not all) web hosts do put limitations on hardware usage in some form or other.  While I have never heard of it being done that way, after reading their documentation it appears to be an decent option.

I know other hosts, such as GoDaddy typically impose a hard limit but have "dedicated" resources to the site.  For example, here's their grid for [Linux hosting](https://www.godaddy.com/help/resource-limits-12001)

[image: Linux Hosting Diagram]

What I have included here is what I'm used to seeing when determining hosted resources.